# Play audio url on windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, audio, stream

I'm going to write a function to play a `mp3 file` from an `URL` on `Windows Mobile 6.0` without downloading all the stream to mobile. I read some documentation and faced some problem that.

Using  [`NAudio.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184683/play-audio-from-a-stream-using-c)
         :  The dll is not compatible for Windows Mobile

Using  [`DirectShowLib.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857546/how-to-access-an-audio-stream-using-directshow-net-c)  : have not found way to get from audio stream.

Is it true that we can't get an `audio Url Stream` in Windows Mobile 6.0? Is there any way or any dll else to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out [Bass library](http://www.un4seen.com/filez/4/Bass24.Net_compact.zip) work well on my specific issue - play mp3 audio from url on windows mobile 6.

Add bass_cp.dll to your solution. And make sure to copy the bass.dll to your execute directory.

And what you need to do is very simple:

```
            int stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateURL(strUrl, 0, 0, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero);
            Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream, false);
```

Of course after you register for the dll. Then add this code line at first:

```
          BassNet.Registration(string email, activated key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which windows mobile? 6.5 or 7?

7 uses Silverlight so it should be really easy to do smooth streaming (never tried it).

6+ I'm not so sure, maybe use a WCF filestream to get the stream?